# Create an index with both indexed and `INCLUDE` columns in PostgreSQL using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

What I want to create is one of the indexes that has some columns indexed and others included. This kind of index is described by PostgreSQL in their documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/indexes-index-only-scans.html)

The SQL query to create the index looks something like `CREATE INDEX tab_x_y ON tab(x) INCLUDE (y);`

Looking at the ActiveRecord PostgreSQL adapter documentation [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-postgresql-extensions/0.8.0/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLIndexDefinition#initialize-instance_method)

**I don't see any option for me to use this `INCLUDE` column feature.**

**Do I have to run this as a raw SQL query? Is there another way?**

Notes

1. I am not asking how to run a query or which index will be used for a query.
2. I am not asking how to create a regular index using ActiveRecord.
3. I am not asking how to create a migration using ActiveRecord.
4. I specifically want information about how to create a specific kind of index with a specific option.

Comment: I haven't done it, so suggestion rather than answer, but you could try using ``create_index`` rather than ``add_index``. ``create_index`` supports Postgres-specific options. ``create_index`` takes an ``:expression`` parameter which might allow you to add the ``INCLUDE``. Check out the [API docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activerecord-postgresql-extensions/0.8.0/ActiveRecord%2FConnectionAdapters%2FPostgreSQLAdapter:create_index).

Comment: @hrdwdmrbl did you get it?
It seems like we can use the create_index as rmlockerd suggested but I'd like to know if you manage to do it in another way.

Comment: @JoãoRamires It's been so long I forget. Since then I've become more comfortable with raw SQL and so I would just use that.

Comment: Oh, I've just answered your question and I didn't see your reply to my comment haha. That's exactly what I did. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 4):

Hey I didn't manage to use add_index neither created_index so I just used raw SQL.

Here's how:

```rb
def up
    execute <<-SQL
      create index my_index
      on table (column1, column2, ..., columnN)
      include (column1, column2, columnN)
    SQL
end
```

Comment: I always use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query("CREATE ...")`. I didn't know about this `execute` method. I assume it's special method for migrations, eh? Does it behave different in any way than `exec_query`?

Comment: Yep, you can check it here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#when-helpers-aren-t-enough